# Viewing class/protocol hierarchy in XCode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've come to iOS from Java world, and one of the most useful features in Java is JavaDoc. It is possible to see ALL implementors of specific interface or descendants of specific class with ease. Is there something similar in XCode 5?
Yes, there are Symbol Navigator, but it shows either hierarchy of ALL classes/protocols or only project-specific classes. And what I want is to quickly find out, for example, all descendants of `UIDynamicBehavior` class. How to do it fast and efficent in XCode 5?
Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually not an answer you do want to hear, but you should try [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/). If you're from Java world, you're probably familiar with IntelliJ IDEA, which is basically what AppCode is.

`^H` and ...

[image: Class Hierarchy]

Comment: Oh, thanks :) I'll consider trying it. However, I have read that AppCode isn't that good at UI as XCode are...

Comment: You can download & test, there's trial version. Also they did release UI Designer in December, here's blog post about it http://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/2013/12/ui-designer-plugin-for-appcode-is-available-in-early-preview/

Comment: AppCode have many bugs right now, atleast for Swift 3 language... Also if you run OSX under VMWare than AppCode have drastically decreased response speed (very large latency between every action) in comparing to XCode. So i am searching the solution for XCode too...